# (C++) Initializing and Declaring elements within a Two Dimensional Vector

Tags: c++

I'm having an awkward result when I run my program after creating this 2D vector. The program actually crashes when it launches. But I'm basically trying to input a set of data for a 2D vector that is meant to retain the amount of bushels of certain crops in the first column (as ints), and then to retain the yield ratio of each crop (as an int). I haven't declared the yield ratio yet, but even if the 2nd column is left empty (in terms of each element's value) it shouldn't have a problem. Here's my code:

```
vector<vector<int> >crops(2, vector<int>(43));
    crops[0][0]=0;  //Arugula
    crops[1][0]=2000000;  //Beans
    crops[2][0]=0;  //Beets
    crops[3][0]=0;  //Cabbages
    crops[4][0]=0;  //Cammomile
    crops[5][0]=0;  //Carrots
    crops[6][0]=0;  //Catmint
    crops[7][0]=0;  //Celery
    crops[8][0]=0;  //Coriander
    crops[9][0]=0;  //Corn
    crops[10][0]=0; //Cucumbers
    crops[11][0]=0; //Eggplants
    crops[12][0]=2000000; //Fennel
    crops[13][0]=1500000; //Flax
    crops[14][0]=0; //Garlix
    crops[15][0]=0; //Greenwoad
    crops[16][0]=0; //Hem
    crops[17][0]=0; //Leeks
    crops[18][0]=0; //Lettuce
    crops[19][0]=0; //Madder
    crops[20][0]=0; //Mint
    crops[21][0]=0; //Mustard
    crops[22][0]=5000000; //Oats
    crops[23][0]=0; //Onions
    crops[24][0]=0; //Parsnips
    crops[25][0]=0; //Parsely
    crops[26][0]=2500000; //Peas
    crops[27][0]=0; //Poppy
    crops[28][0]=0; //Potatoes
    crops[29][0]=0; //Pumpkins
    crops[30][0]=0; //Radishes
    crops[31][0]=0; //Rutabagas
    crops[32][0]=0; //Spinach
    crops[33][0]=4000000; //Spring Barley
    crops[34][0]=0; //Squash
    crops[35][0]=0; //Tomatoes
    crops[36][0]=0; //Turnips
    crops[37][0]=0; //Vetches
    crops[38][0]=0; //Weld
    crops[39][0]=0; //Woad
    crops[40][0]=6000000; //Barley - Winter Crop
    crops[41][0]=5000000; //Mixtill - Winter Crop
    crops[42][0]=4000000; //Wheat - Winter Crop
```

Though, I have to leave for work now, but I will be able to respond to any answers once I return tonight. Thank you for those who are trying to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Swap your subscript indices.

```
crops[13][0] -> crops[0][13]
```

When you declared

```
vector<vector<int> >crops(2, vector<int>(43));
```

You created a vector which is value-initialised with 2 vectors, each of which was value-initialised with 43 ints (meaning they are initialised to 0). There are two vectors in the outer vector so you can only do crops[0] or crops[1] without reading someone else's memory.

Alternatively, of course, you could just change the declaration to:

```
vector<vector<int> >crops(43, vector<int>(2));
```